# Consumos oauth invalido en typescript

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Tengo una consulta en una aplicacion **OAuth** y en caso de que el **access token** haya *caducado* quiero automáticamente pedir uno nuevo al token endpoint pero, ¿cómo hago eso en la misma cadena de eventos?

Es decir:

> El sistema pide el recurso con el access token pero este es rechazado.

Requiero que el mismo sistema y sin la participación del usuario pida un nuevo token al token endpoint y con el nuevo se pida el recurso.

Este proceso debería ser transparente a **sólo un click**, ¿alguien tiene idea como se hace eso en **Angular 2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenos dias, 
luego de tanta discusión y luego de haber leido este link que me parece el mas razonable :
http://www.redotheweb.com/2015/11/09/api-security.html
lo que se debe utilizar es un cookie y un token tambien en el session storage o localstorage lo que hace invulnerable a ataques "directos" por ambos lados, es decir hacer llamadas desde otro dominio o hacer llamadas por insercion de scripts, para que sea totalmente seguro ya sea usar oauth u otro.

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando Oauth lo recomendable es que tu servicio regrese 3 cosas

- Tiempo De vida: para saber cuando caduca
- accessToken: su nombre lo dice
- Refreshtoken: el refresh token permite solicitar más accesstokens

El refreshtoken no tiene fecha de expiración como el accesstoken y generalmente es de **UN SOLO USO**, una vez usado ya no funciona más, a diferencia del access token que si puedes seguir usandolo, por lo que si la petición del nuevo accesstoken falla entonces el usurio tendra que introducir nuevamente sus credenciales (se tendra que logear de nuevo vamos).

Una vez usado el refreshtoken debe regresar las mismas 3 cosas.

Lo que recomiendo es que guardes el refreshtoken en tu servidor de applicación y hagas mediante ajax/$http una llamada a algun endpoint (ej. https://midominio/api/v1/refreshtoken) para que el servidor tramite con el servidor de autenticación el nuevo accesstoken.

La implentación del lado del cliente varia dependiendo del servidor de autenticación y que librería de Oauth este usando.

Este proceso algunos lo llaman el "baile de Oauth" seria cada que tu token caduque, es molesto si pero esta pensado para la seguridad al fin y al cabo.

Comment: Hola está parte : El refreshtoken no tiene fecha de expiración como el accesstoken y generalmente es de UN SOLO USO, una vez usado ya no funciona más, a diferencia del access token que si puedes seguir usandolo, por lo que si la petición del nuevo accesstoken falla entonces el usurio tendra que introducir nuevamente sus credenciales (se tendra que logear de nuevo vamos). CREO QUE NO ES CORRECTA EL REFRESH TOKEN  SE USA PARA CONSE GUIR VARIOS ACCESS TOKENS  Y SI CADUCA TAMBIEN SOLO QUE ESTE DEPENDE DE LA LOGICA DE APLICACIÓN Y EL ACESS TOKEN SI TIENE CADUCIDAD

Comment: El protocolo ya está funcionando pero nada me impide usarlo para un app web  y que los accesos tokens caduquen digamos en 10 minutos y yo pida uno nuevo es por eso que pregunto si alguien por favor me guía como hago un consumo como expliqué. Ya que es una app web  se basa en una session por inactividad o cierre que es cua do realmente caduca la session  independiente del access token y por eso cuando esté caduca tengo que pedir uno nuevo

Comment: Y el usuario no debería darse cuenta que al fallar el antiguo automáticamente pido uno nuevo y vuelvo a consumir el recurso con el nuevo token  en este caso NO TENGO OTRO SERVICIO CON EL QUE INTERACTUO YO SIRVO DE OAUTH Y TAMBIEN DE RESOURCE SERVER Y LA WEB DE CLIENTE EL BAILE ESE ES ENTRE EL CLEINTE Y AMBOS SERVIDORES

Comment: encontre la parte que te digo : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-14

Comment: en esa hoja dice que el cliente puede ser una aplicacion web con credenciales publicas es decir que el refresh token y access token pueden estar en el cliente  interactuando completamente con el servidor OAUTH sin otro extra

Comment: El RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749, expecifica el acceso al authentication server, NO AL RECURSO, el hecho de que el refresh sea de un solo uso es por seguridad, si actuas como resource server y como application server entonces mejor, cambia de grant y simplemente, generale un accesstoken del lado del servidor cuando caduque, No tiene caso hacer todos esos procesos como bien mencionas

Comment: En todo caso lo que deseas lograr puede hacerse con un setTimeout, programado a 10 minutos(o lo que dure ti lifetime) una vez que caduque el setTimeout pide OTRO token y actualizasas la variable local. Vuelves a iniciar el setTimeout y esperas esos 10 min. Si sale o cualquier cosa el servidor se cierra. La logica que dispara el SetTimeout corre de las validaciones que quieras(si ha estado activo o cualquier cosa que deses).
El setTimeout lo realizas  SI y solo SI se han cumplido tus validaciones $http y listo tienes tu token

Comment: El access token puede que darse inactivo por diferentes maneras y así necesitaría un job que pida cada ese tiempo que podría ya no tener sentido

Comment: Lo más lógico es si da 401  ir a pedir un access token ya con el nuevo volver a consultar el recurso pero todo en la misma secuencia

Comment: En estructurado eso es sencillo porque es código bloqueante en javascript ya no tanto porque es no bloqueante 

Comment: Sobre el REFRESH TOKEN no es correcto el REFRESH se puede usar ene veces el que si puede usarse una sola vez es el access token porque puede ser usado para un recurso  y luego ser invalidado apesar que no haya pasado su tiempo como que no el concepto está mal

Comment: Cuando esté refresh token se invalida ya sea por la razón que sea es cuando luego ñ usos finalmente se cierra y el usuario debe loguearse de nuevo

Comment: El problema es que si alguien tiene acceso al refresh token puede estar generando tokens, un atacante con un refresh token que no caduca al primer uso puede joderte toda tu seguridad si seguimos tu logica, por eso se deja el refresh token que tiene tiempo de vida ilimitado y 1 solo uso, mientras el access token se usa para multiples peticiones en un tiempo corto (1 hr por ejemplo)

Comment: Dejar de lado de la App(javascript) el refresh token abres un hueco de seguridad y un atacante XSS puede robar las credenciales por eso usualmente es el server el que hace la transacción del nuevo token. Por lo que toda tu implementación Oauth se vuelve inútil si al final de cuenta estas dejando huecos de seguridad.

Comment: Eso no es un problema a considerar  , eso pasa con un sessionid en los sitios web  o un Jwt  por lo que eso no es un problema  es como si dijeras si alguien tiene mi  contraseña puede estarse entrando a mi sistema jaja

Comment: Pero eso no era la consulta si no voy por como hacer el consumo no el uso del protocolo que en ningún lugar indica el refresh toque de un solo uso eso está mal el refresh token es para generar varios access token no sólo  uno si no que chiste tiene que exista si el auth end point te daría un access token. Y ahí acaba todo  justamente este protocolo es usado para que si el access token es interceptado sólo se pueda usar un tiempo y no para siempre te recomiendo que leas el protocolo en la parte de refresh token y para que sirve

Comment: Creo que mi pregunta la replanteare por que era sobre cómo hacer un consumo condicional y secuencial de varios rest no el uso del oauth

Comment: encontre esto que aclara las dudas :